# Ranking and subranking rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have the following dataset, that I would like to rank by region, and also by store type (within each region).

[image: Dataset]

Is there a slick way of coding these 2 columns in python?

Data:

```
print (df)
    Region ID Location store Type ID  Brand share
0           1              Warehouse         1.97
1           1              Warehouse         0.24
2           1           Super Centre         0.21
3           1              Warehouse         0.13
4           1         Mini Warehouse         0.10
5           1           Super Centre         0.07
6           1         Mini Warehouse         0.04
7           1           Super Centre         0.02
8           1         Mini Warehouse         0.02
9          10              Warehouse         0.64
10         10         Mini Warehouse         0.18
11         10              Warehouse         0.13
12         10              Warehouse         0.09
13         10           Super Centre         0.07
14         10         Mini Warehouse         0.03
15         10         Mini Warehouse         0.02
16         10           Super Centre         0.02
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code, data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['RegionRank'] = df.groupby('Region ID')['Brand share'].cumcount() + 1
cols = ['Location store Type ID', 'Region ID']
df['StoreTypeRank'] = df.groupby(cols)['Brand share'].cumcount() + 1
print (df)
    Region ID Location store Type ID  Brand share  RegionRank  StoreTypeRank
0           1              Warehouse         1.97           1              1
1           1              Warehouse         0.24           2              2
2           1           Super Centre         0.21           3              1
3           1              Warehouse         0.13           4              3
4           1         Mini Warehouse         0.10           5              1
5           1           Super Centre         0.07           6              2
6           1         Mini Warehouse         0.04           7              2
7           1           Super Centre         0.02           8              3
8           1         Mini Warehouse         0.02           9              3
9          10              Warehouse         0.64           1              1
10         10         Mini Warehouse         0.18           2              1
11         10              Warehouse         0.13           3              2
12         10              Warehouse         0.09           4              3
13         10           Super Centre         0.07           5              1
14         10         Mini Warehouse         0.03           6              2
15         10         Mini Warehouse         0.02           7              3
16         10           Super Centre         0.02           8              2
```

Or [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html), but it return same values for same categories:

```
df['RegionRank'] = (df.groupby('Region ID')['Brand share']
                       .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                       .astype(int))
cols = ['Location store Type ID', 'Region ID']
df['StoreTypeRank'] = (df.groupby(cols)['Brand share']  
                           .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                           .astype(int))
print (df)
    Region ID Location store Type ID  Brand share  RegionRank  StoreTypeRank
0           1              Warehouse         1.97           1              1
1           1              Warehouse         0.24           2              2
2           1           Super Centre         0.21           3              1
3           1              Warehouse         0.13           4              3
4           1         Mini Warehouse         0.10           5              1
5           1           Super Centre         0.07           6              2
6           1         Mini Warehouse         0.04           7              2
7           1           Super Centre         0.02           8              3
8           1         Mini Warehouse         0.02           8              3
9          10              Warehouse         0.64           1              1
10         10         Mini Warehouse         0.18           2              1
11         10              Warehouse         0.13           3              2
12         10              Warehouse         0.09           4              3
13         10           Super Centre         0.07           5              1
14         10         Mini Warehouse         0.03           6              2
15         10         Mini Warehouse         0.02           7              3 <-same value .02 
16         10           Super Centre         0.02           7              2 <-same value .02
```